# App not fullscreen on tablet

Tags: android

Is there a way to make sure an application runs in a small screen on a tablet? I need to give a demo of my app with a beamer. I'm going to use my tablet with micro-hdmi... But the app is shown on fullscreen. And it's ugly. It is designed for smartphones only... Someone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

try to run in the app in Compatibility Mode

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html

and try to fallow UI guideline to Supporting Multiple Screens to look it fine

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Timon, I believe that, in general, there is no quick and easy way to do this, but it is possible. What you could do - and I am not sure if your demo warrants all this effort - is to root your tablet device and then finding and installing a custom ROM that allows a custom DPI value to be set on a per app basis.

Of course, the above assumes that this app is written by someone else and you do not have the source code. If, however, it is your own app, then I would follow Dheeresh Singh's recommendation.

Hope this helps. Good luck!